# Sorting works list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have following code that I would like to sort.
How could I do this? (written in slim)

```
@feature_works = Work.find([77, 103, 223, 211, 117]) unless Rails.env.development?
```

I would like to sort this list so that works will be listed from large number to small numbers.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@feature_works  = Work.where(id: [77,103,223,211,117]).order(id: :desc)
```

Comment: `where` and `find` do not have the same behaviour. You should probably use `find` with `sort_by` instead of `where` with `order`.

Comment: I would argue that .where is the appropriate method to use here, as .find will raise an error if the record(s) cannot be found- error avoidance.

Comment: Thanks @Dnyanarth! and everyone who helped me out! It worked fine!